# Flutter and Firebase Analytics - events works in DEBUG VIEW but when build in RELEASE MODE - activity is not shown in Firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I added Firebase to my Flutter project, and all was working fine using Debug mode and DebugView.

I decided to install app on my phone using `flutter run --release` and it looks like it is not longer working.

In the picture below those 5 blue bars indicate my activity when I was using my app in Debug mode (all was working fine).

Lack of bars, encircled with `?` mark (thus Firebase see no activity at all) is when I built and run my app in `--release` mode.

Any idea what is going on?

[image]